# Performing Complex Join in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am very new to Nifi and trying to perform a SQL against SQL server which has multiple tables being joined and also selecting attributes from each one. How can we perform this in Nifi. I am seeing "Generate Table Fetch" which allows me to mention "Table Name" and its "Where Clause". Not sure, how do we perform complex join if there are multiple tables involved.

Example-

```
Select 
a.col1,
a.col2,
b.col3,
b.col4,
c.col5,
c.col6
from a left outer join b
on a.colx=b.colx
inner join c
on a.coly = c.coly
where exists (some condition etc)
```

Thanks,
Siddhartha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ***`ExecuteSQL/ExecuteSQLRecord(NiFi-1.8+)`*** processor and keep your **query** in `SQL select query` property.

**Configure/Enable** the **dbcp connection pool**.

Keep in mind ***`ExecuteSQL`*** processor **doesn't store the state**:

- So if you want to run the processor incrementally then you need to store the state in NiFi (or) externally then pull the state value every time and execute the your query.
- Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/187764/can-executesql-processor-store-state-for-increment.html) link for more details regards to storing/fetching state using NiFi.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked fine for me. If i had to use a parameterized date in my sql statement, how to pass the value dynamically. For example my where condition looks like "where business_date=$run_time_business_date"

Comment: @Sidd, if you are already have `run_time_business_date` attribute associated with the flowfile then you need to use **"where business_date=${run_time_business_date}"** to get value of the attribute..

Comment: Hi Shu, where do i define this parameter run_time_business_date?